# I need to know what this line of code does in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have been given this django project. I have been trying to run it and figure it out. I have a view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def view(Request,viewName,id):
    print '-------------------start    ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    try:
        c = globals()[viewName](viewName, viewName, None, Request, id)
        data = c.render()
        print '-------------------end    ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
        return data

    except Exception as ex1:
        print '----------------'
        print
        print 'Error in importing View: %s.' % viewName
        print ex1
        print traceback.format_exc()
        print '----------------'
    print '-------------------end    ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    return HttpResponse()
```

What I need to know is what the fifth line does since I get a KeyError Exception there:

```
c = globals()[viewName](viewName, viewName, None, Request, id)
```

here is the traceback:

```
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] -------------------start    2016-09-24 09:42:55.045115
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] ----------------
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] 
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] Error in importing View: HealthSearchPolicy.
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] u'HealthSearchPolicy'
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-]   File "/home/shirvani/Desktop/Archive/beasy/views.py", line 167, in view
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-]     c = globals()[viewName](viewName, viewName, None, Request, id)
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] KeyError: u'HealthSearchPolicy'
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] 
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] ----------------
2016-09-24 09:42:55+0330 [-] -------------------end    2016-09-24 09:42:55.04629
```

Comment: i think you should find the guy who wrote this code and beat him up. Apart from the fact that the code is poorly designed, using `globals()` and returning an empty response at the end makes logic even more terrible. You can start debugging by printing out `globals()` and see what's in that.

Comment: already did that, its and endless list of ... well globals :D... what I  don't understand is the format of that line. what does the parenthesis do?

Comment: The result of globals() is a dict. Looking up viewname in that dict returns a function. The parentheses are calling that function with the supplied arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = globals()[viewName](viewName, viewName, None, Request, id)
```

`globals()` gives you dict of global variables. 
Thenwith `[viewName]` its referencing the particular global variable with name matching with value of `viewName` parameter. 
And hopefully its a function, so its called with those parameters.

As for design, somebody tried to create list of functions to be called depending upon value in url.

Instead of all this, you can use django urls framework which does exactly this.